# Algorithms for similarity for words using wikipedia

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, text-analysis

I am looking to calculate the distance between two words

Word1 - ManchesterUnited  Word2 - RyanGiggs

I feel that using wikipedia would be a really good option. 
I would try and determine the distance of both the words from a common category or topic. What algorithms can I use to determine the common topic? 
My next question is how would I get the heirarchy under the common topic so that I can calculate the distance of the words?

I would also like to know if there are any other ways of calculating the distance between two words. It would be good if it is something easy and efficient to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Why not using https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/ which is already trained on WIKI?

Comment: Will this return the distance between the two words? Also how does it work if there are ambiguities in the meanings of the words?

Comment: Yes, distance measure. AFAIN it doesn't support word senses.

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean by 'already trained'? Doesn't this require to train word2vec on Wikipedia (which isn't so trivial)? Are there ready trained options?

Comment: I mean, the system that i have linked is already trained and ready to use. Training such a system is a big pain and might take several weeks to do, even with a very good engineering.